# Find $x$ in the equation $x^x = n$ for a given $n$

Tags: exponentiation

Simply: How do I solve this equation for a given $n \in \mathbb Z$?

$x^x = n$

I mean, of course $2^2=4$ and $3^3=27$ and so on. But I don't understand how to calculate the reverse of this, to get from a given $n$ to $x$.

Comment: Have you tried solving this for small $n$ say $n=2$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I have no idea how to solve this. Of course $2^2=4$ and $3^3=27$, but I have no idea what it should be for $n=2$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Some people automatically downvote posts that show no effort of attempt to solve it themselves. To prevent this in the future, I would include your $2^2$ and $3^3$ in your original post so that it looks like you tried to others.

Comment: The solutions are all $x\in\mathbb{N}$ I think.

Comment: That one has infinite solutions.

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis Why should this have infinite solutions? When $n=27$, my only solution is $x=3$. The $n$ is a given constant from which I want to calculate $x$.

Comment: @ByteCommander You need to find "x" that $x^x=n\in\mathbb{N} and NOT "n".

Comment: Is $x$ also constrained to be in $\mathbb Z$ ? (If not, knowing that $n$ is integer doesn't make the problem simpler.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, $x \in \Bbb R$. There's no such simple restriction unfortunately.

Comment: Then $n\in\mathbb Z$ is of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler:

If
$x^x = n$,
then $x\ln(x) = \ln(n)
=y$.

Let
$f(x) = x\ln(x)-y
$.
$f'(x)
=\ln(x)+1
$.

Applying Newton's iteration,
starting with $x = \frac{y}{\ln y}$,
$x_{new}
=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
=x-\frac{x\ln(x)-y}{\ln(x)+1}
=\frac{x\ln(x)+x-x\ln(x)+y}{\ln(x)+1}
=\frac{x+y}{\ln(x)+1}
$.

Iterate until cooked.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But maybe the formula would be more clear if you don't substitute $y = ln(n)$...

Comment: And I just noticed that your value for $y$ must be manually set to $1$ or something similar if $n<1$. Else we get a problem because it would evaluate to $ln(0)$.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes, of course, it is recommended that you choose $y$ so that you can avoid such troubles.  Interestingly, if you choose different $y$ values, you may experience different complex or real results... (try Google calculator for complex logarithm)

Answer (score 3):

See this wikipedia article: [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

If $x^x=n,$ then $$x=\dfrac{\ln n}{W(\ln n)},$$ Where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Comment: Hey out of curiosity , could you show your steps how you got to x= ?

Comment: It may required a little knowledge about  Lambert W function. You can find this from the given link.

Comment: That requires more than a little knowledge, and I've never heard of the Lambert W function before... I would need to find a way to code this in Python, but I can't use the `scipy` package where this function would be built in... :-/

Comment: @ByteCommander Basically, you're not going to find a solution in terms of elementary functions. You either have to use a numerical approximation algorithm (as noted in marty cohen's answer), or a special function such as this (Lambert W function).

Comment: @ByteCommander If you wish to calculate the Lambert W function, there are some easy methods you may find in the Lambert W tag.